# Orchard CMS 1.7 - Extend Media Content Type to get Tag type functionality

Tags: orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

**Problem:**

I have situation where I have to tag the media items with geoIDs. I have been trying to replicate the functionalists of Tags Module and have created the models, Views, Drives and Handler for GeoObject. My problem is that when I load the edit view of an Image, I don't get my GeoObject edit view.

Here's my Handler:

```
class GeoObjectsPartHandler:ContentHandler {
    public GeoObjectsPartHandler(IRepository<GeoObjectsPartRecord> repository, IGeoObjectService geoObjectService)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

        OnIndexing<GeoObjectsPart>(
            (context, geoObjectsPart) =>
            {
                foreach (var geoObject in geoObjectsPart.CurrentGeoObjects)
                {
                    context.DocumentIndex.Add("geoObjects", geoObject.GeoObjectName).Analyze();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
[UsedImplicitly]
class GeoObjectsPartDriver: ContentPartDriver<GeoObjectsPart>
{
    private static readonly char[] _disalowedChars = new[] { '<', '>', '*', '%', ':', '&', '\\', '"', '|' };
    private const string TemplateName = "Parts/GeoObjects";
    private readonly INotifier _notifier;
    private readonly IGeoObjectService _geoObjectService;

    public GeoObjectsPartDriver(IGeoObjectService geoObjectService, INotifier notifier)
    {
        _geoObjectService = geoObjectService;
        _notifier = notifier;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    protected override string Prefix
    {
        get { return "GeoObjects"; }
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(GeoObjectsPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_GeoObjects_Edit",
                () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: TemplateName, Model: BuildEditorViewModel(part), Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(GeoObjectsPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var model = new EditGeoObjectsViewModel();
        return ContentShape("Parts_GeoObjects_Edit",
                () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: TemplateName, Model: model, Prefix: Prefix));

    }

    private static EditGeoObjectsViewModel BuildEditorViewModel(GeoObjectsPart part)
    {
        return new EditGeoObjectsViewModel
        {
            GeoObjects = string.Join(", ", part.CurrentGeoObjects.Select((t, i) => t.GeoObjectName).ToArray())
        };
    }

    protected override void Importing(GeoObjectsPart part, ImportContentContext context)
    {
        var geoObjectString = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "GeoObjects");
    }

    protected override void Exporting(GeoObjectsPart part, ExportContentContext context)
    {
        context.Element(part.PartDefinition.Name).SetAttributeValue("GeoObjects", String.Join(",", part.CurrentGeoObjects.Select(t => t.GeoObjectName)));
    }
}
```

Migration:

```
using Orchard.Data.Migration;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData;
using Orchard.Core.Contents.Extensions;
namespace ePageo.TUI.MediaManager
{
    public class MediaManagerDataMigration : DataMigrationImpl
    {
        public int Create()
        {
            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("GeoObjectsPartRecord",
                table => table
                    .ContentPartRecord()
                );

            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("GeoObjectRecord",
                table => table
                    .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
                    .Column<string>("GeoObjectName")
                );

            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ContentGeoObjectRecord",
                table => table
                    .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
                    .Column<int>("GeoObjectRecord_Id")
                    .Column<int>("GeoObjectsPartRecord_Id")
                );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("GeoObjectsPart", builder => builder.Attachable());


            return 1;
        }

        public int UpdateFrom1()
        {
            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("GeoObjectsPart", builder => builder
                .WithDescription("Allows to add Geo-object ids to the particular media Item."));
            return 2;
        }

        public int UpdateFrom2()
        {
            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Image", td => td
                .WithPart("GeoObjectsPart")
            );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Video", td => td
                .WithPart("GeoObjectsPart")
            );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Audio", td => td
                .WithPart("GeoObjectsPart")
            );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Document", td => td
                .WithPart("GeoObjectsPart")
            );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("OEmbed", td => td
                .WithPart("GeoObjectsPart")
            );
            return 3;
        }

    }
}
```

Placement.info:

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_GeoObjects_Edit="Content:12"/>
</Placement>
```

I don't think I have problem in my model since its the exact replication of Orchard Tags Models. In fact all of the above files are just that.

I just cannot get the Geo Object edit view to show up in Image (Media) edit view.

I need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the code to work.

Turns out I had to declare the Driver and Handler classes to `public`.

I just switched from PHP to ASP.NET few months ago so since if we did not declare any scope PHP would take it as public, I thought it'd be the same with ASP.NET.

The code itself had no other problem except for that.